# Batch file start command launching process but not launching GUI window

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

So i'm trying to do a simple task restart on a box that needs a GUI app running on the desktop.  I'm using the `start` command to call the application.  For some reason when i run it from the task scheduler it does everything it's supposed to except launch the application's GUI window.  I can see the process running in Task Manager, but no GUI launches.  This is Windows 2008 R2.

Here's the script replacing the app with notepad (which has the same problem).

```
@echo off
:: Kill notepad.exe if running.

TaskKill /IM notepad.exe /F

:: Wait for app to close.
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 8000 >NUL

:: Check to make sure app isn't running, then start it.

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" 2>NUL | find /I "notepad.exe">NUL
IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" START "" "notepad.exe"

EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Is this a Windows 2008R2 Task Scheduler gotcha, or a batch file gotcha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the option to "Run only when user is logged in" selected. Otherwise the task will be launched as an invisible background process.